# Uniform Convergence of sequence of functions $\int_{0}^{x} \sin^2(t+\frac{1}{n}) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Given a sequence $f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \sin^2(t+\frac{1}{n})\ dt$. Now for checking the uniformity $$|f_n(x)-g(x)|\leq\int_{0}^{x}\left|\,\sin^2\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sin^2(t)\right|\ dt$$

where, $g(x)$ is the uniform limit of $\sin^2(t+\frac{1}{n})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Now, $|\sin^2(t+\frac{1}{n})-\sin^2(t)|\leq \frac{2}{n}$

$|f_n(x)-g(x)|\leq \frac{2x}{n}$

The above inequality implies the convergence is not uniform in $[0,\infty)$ but answer given to me states it is uniform over this interval. So the question which one is correct?

Comment: You cannot conclude the convergence is not uniform from the inequality you got, because the upper bound $2x/n$ may not be tight, i.e. $\sup_{x\geq 0}2x/n=\infty$ doesn't imply $\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-g(x)|\to\infty$

Comment: That's precisely the concern of mine, so I believe there must be a better upper bound which I'm not able to get !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

\begin{align*}
f_n(x) - g(x)
&= \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} \sin^2 t \, dt - \int_{0}^{x} \sin^2 t \, dt \\
&= \int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} \sin^2 t \, dt - \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} \sin^2 t \, dt
\end{align*}

and hence

$$ |f_n(x) - g(x)| \leq \frac{2}{n}. $$

Answer (score 0):

1) I think, you got $g$ as the pointwise limit of $f$. If you know, that $g$ is the uniform limit of $f$, then there is nothing to prove anymore...

2) The inequality doesn't prove anything. To prove the uniformity of the convergence the inequality is not sufficient, but it doesn't disprove it either!
To prove that $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $g$, you have to find $x_n\in[0,\infty)$ such that $|f_n(x_n)-g(x_n)|\not\to 0$.

Comment: I know that $\sin^2(t+\frac{t}{n}$ converges to $\sin^2(x)$ uniformly and this will imply that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly, but still what would be good upper bound to prove it using norm.